# Inappbrowser works fine in Android but not in ios. Specific to ionic3

Tags: ionic3

Inappbrowser works fine in Android, but it’s not working in iOS device, it’s opening url in system default browser (safari) instead of inside App.

Already tried with var target = "_blank"; var target = "_self";

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and check your problem is still in this way?

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

If the problem is still probably you miss some part of the configuration or whitelist config in meta.

Also, it's good to check this forum page: 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/inappbrowser-ios-issue-url-not-opening-in-app/70864/4